# What is a "quasi-demonic essence"?

Tags: anima-beyond-fantasy

While browsing a compilation of artifacts in Anima's Prometheum Exxet I discovered Dunkelschwert, a demonic sword that transform its bearer's essence into a quasi-demonic one.
What is a quasi demonic essence and what are its effects on a character?

Answer (score 1):

Well, my best guess is that the people affected by the item could follow the things described in "Anima those who walked amongst us". In particular on page 38, where it mentions Demonic souls. A way to interpret it might be treating the person as if they were a fourth or fifth hierarchy demon.

The book also mentions a special way to handle Demonic familiars, could treat the weapon as if it were a demonic familiar. Strictly speaking, the sword would definitely have some RP implications.

Comment: Cutting and pasting book material “because not everyone has it” is an obvious type of copyright violation that we're not OK with on this site. If people need to buy a book to understand and use the answer… then they should buy the book. ;) If you like, you can explain why it is worthwhile to own/borrow/use that book by (in your own words) describing the usefulness of the material it contains regarding this question.